# Bundling and Minification with included Javascripts doesn't make sense in MVC 5 project template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification

This is the default MVC 5 project's BundleConfig.

As you see in debug mode, EnableOptimization by default is disabled.

First two bundles dont make any sense to me, because each one will include whole bunch of duplicated scripts (minified and non-minified, including intellisense, validate-vsdoc etc...).

What is the point including all these JavaScript files and have Optimization disabled? Even with Optimization enabled, if I set **BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;**, it still doesnt make any sense to include all of these JavaScript files.

Or, if I set **BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;**, then why would I ever need to have minified JavaScript files at all, they all will be minified, no?

Am I missing something here? Many Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Microsoft Blog](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) can explain a lot of what your asking but to sum it up, when you use bundeling asp.net is smart and if your in debug mode it will only include the full `.js` file so if you have to do any debugging on it you can see the normal code and read it. If your in release mode (`BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;,`) then it only includes the `.min.js` file as to serve up a smaller more stream lined copy. The other files (intellises, map, etc) are there just to help developers code easier.

As for why you need the `.min.js` files it is to save on server resources. ASP.Net will automatically do minification for you but that eats resources as well as it is a modertate minification. If you want to save those resources OR do a heavy minification you can make your own `.min.js` file but you are not forced to include one.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about that article.